# Fit a line to 3 spatial points

Tags: r, line, average

I have a set of lon/ lat coordinates that locates lines. Each line is characterized by 3 points, the start, center and end which were measured using a handheld GPS. Since the individual coordinates are very much likely to be imprecise (which would give me crooked lines), I want to get an "corrected line" with a given length (*50m*), centered on the center coordinate and with the average direction of the vectors start-center and center-end.
The lines should subsequently be buffered by *2m* to generate rectangles, but at first I need the lines to start with.
I tried to implement this in R. It's been some time since I last had vector geometry and I don't know how this all works on a spherical surface. Maybe someone has an idea?

Edit: I have the following code so far (it only uses the first row of the dataframe, i.e. the first line, and will be looped once it works)

```
# Calculate the length of a 1 degree difference
earth_circumference <- 40075016.7
for(i in 1:nrow(coords)){
  coords$d_m_lon[i] <- earth_circumference/360*cos(abs(coords$c_lat[1])*pi/180)
  coords$d_m_lat[i] <- earth_circumference/360
}

# Claculate the difference in degree that 1m at the surface makes
coords$m_d_lon <- 1/coords$d_m_lon
coords$m_d_lat <- 1/coords$d_m_lat

# Calculate average transect directions
points <- data.frame(
  x = c(coords$s_lon[1], coords$c_lon[1], coords$e_lon[1]),
  y = c(coords$s_lat[1], coords$c_lat[1], coords$e_lat[1])
)
mod <- lm(points$y ~ points$x)
a <- coefficients(mod)[1]
b <- coefficients(mod)[2]

# Calculate polygon points
center <- c(coords$c_lon[1], coords$c_lat[1])
direction <- c(b-a, 1)/sqrt((b-a)^2 + 1)
start <- center + 25*c(coords$m_d_lon[1], coords$m_d_lat[1])*direction
end <- center - 25*c(coords$m_d_lon[1], coords$m_d_lat[1])*direction

dx <- end[1] - start[1]
dy <- end[2] - start[2]
ortho <- c(-dy, dx)

A <- start + c(coords$m_d_lon[1], coords$m_d_lat[1])*ortho/sqrt(ortho[1]^2+ortho[2]^2)
B <- start + c(coords$m_d_lon[1], coords$m_d_lat[1])*ortho/sqrt(ortho[1]^2+ortho[2]^2)
C <- end + c(coords$m_d_lon[1], coords$m_d_lat[1])*ortho/sqrt(ortho[1]^2+ortho[2]^2)
D <- end + c(coords$m_d_lon[1], coords$m_d_lat[1])*ortho/sqrt(ortho[1]^2+ortho[2]^2)
```

where *coords* is a *dataframe* with the coordinates of the measured start, center and end points of the lines.
Each row of the dataframe contains the points of one line, so e.g. *s_lat[1]* is the latitude of the first **start** point, *c_lon[1]* is the longitude of the first **center** point, *e_lat[1]* is the latitude of the first **end** point and so on.

Now, the problem seems to be somewhere in the calculation of the polygon points: I want to generate the new *start* and *end* points of each line by going *25m* in each direction along the regression line given by the linear model, starting at the *center* (subsequently, to get corner points A-D of a rectangle, I want to go *1m* from there, in a direction orthogonal to the regression line). However, 25m is not the same length in latitude and longitude, because they have to be scaled with the values *m_d_lat[i]* and *m_d_lon[i]* for each line *i*. It somehow shifts my points and I don't know yet why and how I can solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! How did you try implementing it in R?

Comment: So far I have only imported the points, and scribbled notes that I discarded later on...

Comment: You really want to do this on the sphere? So that your "lines" are great circle segments? I'm not sure what your "average direction" means either. Could you draw a diagram and add this to our question?

Comment: Ok, I addes some code and tried to clarify the problem: Since the distances are very small, I can regard the earth as flat; the supposed length of my lines is known (50m per line), but I have to convert this value in degrees. Now when a line is not parallel to lon or lat, I have to scale the length in degrees with different factors for different directions which seems not to work properly with my current code...

Comment: Let's simplify. If "start point" is on a clock face where the number "1" is and "centre point" is at the centre, and "end point" is at "5", where is your output line going to go? From 12 to 6? From 9 to 3? But always through the centre?